# How to add same data object to a document (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I am trying to uniquely store data for each server in a database, I want to be able to store multiple of the same data object. I am only able to store one because if I attempt to store another one it just replaces it, which is the issue here.

**Schema**

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    reactionRole: {
        type: Object,
        required: false,
}
});
```

**Screenshot of the Data**

[image]

**Trying to Accomplish**

I want to be able to store the same object here but with different data obviously, would I have to  make the schema take a Array and just insert it? I am not really sure how to work around this, thanks!

**Example**

This is how I want the data to be, the option to be able to add more onto the document instead of replacing it. Should I use an array or what's a solution?

```js
reactionRole: {
<Role.name> config 1: {
Enabled: true,
Added_By: id,
MessageID: msg.id,
Emoji: <emoji>,
Role: id,
},
<Role.name> config 2: {
Enabled: true,
Added_By: id,
MessageID: msg.id,
Emoji: <emoji>,
Role: id,
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. I changed the schema to an array and sent the data as objects.

Comment: Will be helpful to share the new schema here

Comment: I just changed `Object` to `Array` for the schema